# how to connect visualvm with the application running in kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, jmx, visualvm

I have an application running as a pod in a Kubernetes cluster, specifically on an Amazon EKS cluster. I want to monitor the heap size of this application using VisualVM. How can I connect VisualVM to the application in my Kubernetes cluster, and what configurations do I need to make? Do I need to modify the deployment YAML file, or can I make changes to the Dockerfile for this purpose?

expecting answers to solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can use port-forward direct on the pod and un visualVM in localhost:31743.
Use kubcet get pod to know fullname of the pod.

```
kubectl port-forward mendix-app-XXX  31743:31743
```

Comment: the port forwarding is not working

Comment: you get an error message ?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure where your **VisualVM** running. If it's running on the same **Kubernetes** cluster you can use the service name to connect with **Application**.

If it's somewhere out and you have to expose your service to the internet and connect to **VisualVM**, you can use service type **LoadBalancer** or Use **ingress**.

You also might like to **whitelist IP** so that over the internet only **VisualVM** can connect to your service.

If your **VisualVM** running on **AWS** cloud **VM**(windows/linux) you can create internal **LB** service type on Kubernetes and expose your service and use that IP.

**Update service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mendix-app-service-lb
  labels:
    app: mendix-k8s
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: jmx
    port: 7845
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mendix-k8s
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 160.2X1.2X4.1/32 #Add your IP here to the whitelist so only you can connect
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Harsh Manvar. My VisualVM is running locally, and I have made modifications to the deployment YAML file. However, it still isn't functioning correctly. What should I do next?

Comment: could you please share the details or yaml file ref of your service ? Not sure what you have modified in deployment yaml would be hard to share any suggestion.

Comment: Hello Harsh Manvar,

I have posted my StatefulSet YAML file in the answer section below because the character count was too long to upload in the comment section. Please find it and help me resolve this issue.

Comment: sure, ideally you should edit question and update if possible please do same by deleting answering.

Comment: you have service type Nodeport if your worker node have public IP you can use NodeIP:NodePort to access your application locally. Or else you can use the service Loadbalancer with service. you can use port-forward also but that's for debugging short live connection it's like you are creating tunell from cluster to local port.

Comment: thanks for your response harsh, if you dont mind could you please tell the configurations i need to make in statefulset yaml file

Comment: Sure but tell me is it part time or long term are you planning ? Is it fine to expose app to internet ?

Comment: yeah harsh its for long term, help me to resolve it!

Comment: apply the above update service.yaml file wait for LoadBalancer to come, `kubectl get svc` and get the ExternalIP and use it to connect.

Comment: thanks harsh for your response , but in our case we run visualvm locally, how can i do it?

Comment: You only said my visualVm run locally 

Comment: do i need to configure anything in statefulset file which i provided earlier? and also i have a doubt how can i enable jmx? . where can i enable it? is it possible to enable jmx in statefulset?

Comment: Not sure, about that please add new question with proper details in new question. in this shared how you can expose you service and connect locally.

Comment: hi harsh , i have posted a new question, please review and suggest some answers

Comment: above answer service did you try ? resolves your answer ? if so feel free to update the status of question or you can also add your own answer and mark it as accepted or do upvote if found it helpful.

Comment: when i try the service which you gave, it returns the loadbalancer url ,not in ip format. what can i do next?